# spl_autoload_register working on localhost but not live server

Tags: php

This code works on my localhost but not live server for some reason.

```
spl_autoload_register(function($className) {
    $folders = [
        'libraries/',
        'controllers/',
    ];
    foreach ($folders as $f) {
        $path = __DIR__ . '/' . $f . $className . '.php';
        if (is_file($path)) {
            require_once $path;
        }
    }
});
```

And the code that will not run is:

```
<?php 
    $navigation = new navigation();
    echo $navigation->index();
?>
```

The page stops at exactly the point that is called. Unfortunately I don't have much to go on because there is no error displayed on when I view the page source.

Comment: What OS's are you using locally and on the server? Windows doesn't care about correct casing on files and folders while linux does.

Comment: Using Mac with MAMP locally and live server is running Linux. If that is what you are referring to by OS's ?

Comment: Yes. Are all files, folders and class names in lower case?

Comment: Um. My model and controller files start with an uppercase letter e.g.: Pages.php The folder names are all lowecase

Comment: The files must match the class name casing, like: `Pages.php` and `class Pages`. When you're using it, it must be `new Pages` etc. Linux is very strict about that.

Comment: Genius. That solved my problem!